# How should scopes be defined for an API ecosystem with OAuth?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, api-design, scopes

As the creator of an API ecosystem with OAuth, you want to allow access to your APIs via scopes that can be attached to an access token. My questions are thus:

- How do YOU define a scope?
- Would you expect any scopes you define to provide access only to resources/methods within a single API, or should a scope include access across multiple APIs?
- How likely are you to define scopes in an API definition file like Swagger/OAS or RAML vs. within some sort of API gateway tool?
- Should scopes be defined outside of the context of a specific API as part of a separate OAuth management tool, alongside things like IdP registration and client application creation?

I realize there may be several possible answers and perspectives on this - that is exactly what I am looking for.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

My OAuth2 server has the ability to create arbitrary scopes. Scopes are similar to 'roles', they describe groups of functionality.

The OAuth2 server is essentially unaware of what theses scopes are. API Resource servers receive Bearer tokens, and based on the bearer tokens find out what scopes are associated with it, and make decisions on what a user can and cannot do with that scope, but to the OAuth2 server, they are opaque strings.

We don't use swagger/RAML.

Comment: Thank you - so with arbitrary scopes, how do you associate specific API functions to a given scope in your system?

Comment: Different resource servers define their own mappings. Given that a scope (to us) is a role, roles are defined by the individual permissions associated to them. This is done in a business logic layer, not a layer that's close to the surface that understands HTTP urls and methods. The fact that something has a HTTP url, method, body and headers is an implementation detail.